# What is the best resource for keeping up with changes to geth/Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum

For example, is there a dev blog or something similar that goes over the changes in new releases of geth, and the reasoning on the new changes? Or is it best to just watch the github repository?

Answer (score 0):

The [official discord channel](https://discordapp.com/invite/nthXNEv)

There is where the developers get around, and there is an announcement channel where you can get all the updates